# How do I convert an Object Array to a Foundry Object Set in my Function?

Tags: palantir-foundry, foundry-code-repositories, foundry-functions

My Function’s input is an Object Array but I want to convert it to an Object Set to have `searchAround` capability. Is this possible within the Function? Or do I have to change the Function input to take an Object Set

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create an Object Set within your Function as follows:

```
Objects.search()
        .myObjectType()
        .filter(x => x.myObjectId.exactMatch(...myObjects.map(y => y.myObjectId))
```